# Scroll not working in overflowing content in Material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, scroll, material-ui, jsx

I am trying to map `dummyData` in `div`. The problem is the scroll doesn't work(especially in mobile screen) when data overflows out of the screen vertically. I tried using the Material UI list instead of div with no success. Here is the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/young-silence-xguov).

```
import React from "react";
import makeStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/makeStyles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  container: {
    bottom: 0,
    position: "fixed"
  },
  bubbleContainer: {
    width: "100%"
  },
  bubble: {
    border: "0.5px solid black",
    borderRadius: "10px",
    margin: "5px",
    padding: "10px",
    paddingTop: "150px",
    paddingBottom: "150px",
    display: "inline-block"
  }
}));

const Demo = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const dummyData = [
    {
      message: "Some random text"
    },
    {
      message: "Some random text"
    },
    {
      message: "Some random text"
    },
    {
      message: "Some random text"
    },
    {
      message: "Some random text"
    }
  ];

  const chatBubbles = dummyData.map((obj, i = 0) => (
    <div className={classes.bubbleContainer}>
      <div key={i++} className={classes.bubble}>
        <div>{obj.message}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  ));
  return <div className={classes.container}>{chatBubbles}</div>;
};

export default Demo;
```

Comment: you need to provide `height` and `overflow` CSS property to your `div` with `bubbleContainer` class

Comment: there is also some margin on body, if it's web-app, I'd suggest using reset.css

Comment: I am already using <CssBaseline /> in index.js.